# @parcel/optimizer-terser: Legacy octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, build, parceljs, parcel

I am getting this error when i try to build from parcel does anyone know how to solve this? it would be really helpful

error ->  Build failed.

@parcel/optimizer-terser: Legacy octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcwB9.png)

the error is ->
Build failed.

@parcel/optimizer-terser: Legacy octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode

C:\Users\intel\Desktop\full stack Web Dev course\udemy\fork\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:31931:53
31930 |             char = state <= 32 ? byte & 61694 >>> type : (byte & 63 | char << 6) >>> 0;

> 31931 | tAt$1(" \x000:XECCCCCN:lDb \x000:XECCCCCNvlDb \x000:XECCCCCN:lDb AAAAA\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00AAAAA0000  >       |      ^ Legacy octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode
> 31932 |             if (state === 0) {
> 31933 |               buffer._contents += A.Primitives_stringFromCharCode(char);

It's likely that Terser doesn't support this syntax yet.

Comment: Please include the error details in the question rather than as a screenshot.